# How can I use a properties file in the "expand" portion of the Gradle Copy task?

Tags: gradle

Lets say I have properties file `config.properties` which has

```
prop1=abc
prop2=xyz
```

and a `template-config.xml` that looks something like

```
<bean id="id1" >
  <property name="prop1" value="${prop1}" />
  <property name="prop2" value="${prop2}" />
</bean>
```

I have 2 Questions:

1. Is there a way I can use the property file in the **expand()** portion of the gradle copy task to inject the properties into the config from **gradle.build.kts**?
2. Is there a way I can use expand to fill in only one of the properties without throwing an error?

So far I have

```
tasks.register<Copy>("create-config-from-template") {
    from("$buildDir/resources/main/template-config.xml")
    into("$buildDir/dist")
    expand(Pair("prop1", "abc"))
}
```

However, this throws an error

> Missing property (prop2) for Groovy template expansion. Defined keys [prop1].

I know that I can also specify the value for prop2 inside "expand()", but for my purposes it would help if I could only inject some of the properties and not others. Is there a simple way to tell gradle not to worry about the other "${}" properties in the file?

If not, is there a way I can use the actual property file as the set of properties to expand? I can't seem to find the Kotlin DSL syntax for this anywhere.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, you can use configure the existing `processResources` task to apply additional configuration to a specific file. In this case `template-config.xml`, for example:

```
tasks.processResources {
    filesMatching("**/template-config.xml") {
        val examplePropertiesTextResource = resources.text.fromFile(layout.projectDirectory.file("example.properties"))
        val exampleProperties = Properties().apply {
            FileInputStream(examplePropertiesTextResource.asFile()).use { load(it) }
        }
        val examplePropertiesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>().apply {
            exampleProperties.forEach { k, v -> put(k.toString(), v) }
        }
        expand(examplePropertiesMap)
    }
}
```

`filesMatching` will match on the file you want. Then the proceeding lines load the properties file, in this case a file name `example.properties` in the project's root directory. It is then transformed into a `Map<String, Any>` and passed to the [`expand`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ContentFilterable.html#expand-java.util.Map-) method.

However, for 2, with the above approach it will fail if any properties are missing. This is because the underlying expansion engine ([`SimpleTemplateEngine`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_simpletemplateengine)) does not allow such configuration

As an alternative, you can use [`ExpandTokens`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) from Apache ANT to achieve the replacement when some properties are missing:

```
tasks.processResources {
    filesMatching("**/template-config.xml") {
        val examplePropertiesTextResource = resources.text.fromFile(layout.projectDirectory.file("example.properties"))
        val exampleProperties = Properties().apply {
            FileInputStream(examplePropertiesTextResource.asFile()).use { load(it) }
        }
        val examplePropertiesMap = mapOf<String, Any>("tokens" to exampleProperties.toMap())
        println(examplePropertiesMap)
        filter(examplePropertiesMap, ReplaceTokens::class.java)
    }
}
```

Note that for `ReplaceTokens`, you must change the placeholders from `${example}` to `@example@`:

```
<bean id="id1" >
    <property name="prop1" value="@prop1@" />
    <property name="prop2" value="@prop2@" />
</bean>
```

This is because Gradle only accepts a `Class` and `ReplaceTokens` is `final`, so you can't extend the class to use `${}` as the placeholders.